# CS0102 error while running ASP.NET application

Tags: c#

I get this error in the App_directory C# code file,

`CS0102: The type ClassName already contains a definition for 'mappingSource'`

It points to line,

`private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();`

What is the likely mistake? Using vs 2008 and .net 3.5

Comment: It's saying `mappingSource` has already been defined elsewhere. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It means the class 'ClassName' already has a 'member' (aka variable) named 'mappingSource' defined. So just choose another name for it and it should compile.